# Difference between std::string and std::u16string (or u32string)

Tags: c++, string, c++11, output

I have referred below posts before asking here:

[std::string, wstring, u16/32string clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438129/stdstring-wstring-u16-32string-clarification)
[std::u16string, std::u32string, std::string, length(), size(), codepoints and characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251340/stdu16string-stdu32string-stdstring-length-size-codepoints-and-ch)

But they don't my question. Look at the simple code below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  char16_t x[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 0 };
  u16string arr = x;

  cout << "arr.length = " << arr.length() << endl;
  for(auto i : arr)
    cout << i << "\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
arr.length = 3  // a + b + c
97
98
99
```

Given that, `std::u16string` consists of `char16_t` and not `char` shouldn't the output be:

```
arr.length = 2  // ab + c(\0)
<combining 'a' and 'b'>
99
```

Please excuse me for the novice question. My requirement is to get clear about the concept of new C++11 strings.

**Edit**:

From @Jonathan's answer, I have got the loophole in my question. My point is that how to initialize the `char16_t`, so that the length of the `arr` becomes `2` (i.e. `ab`, `c\0`).
FYI, below gives a different result:

```
  char x[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 0 };
  u16string arr = (char16_t*)x;  // probably undefined behavior
```

Output:

```
arr.length = 3
25185
99
32767
```

Comment: You have an `array` of `char16_t` elements. You initialize it with `3` elements...

Comment: @JonathanWakely, Yes indeed, had a bit of a conflict between my typing and my thinking :). Point being - initialized with a `fixed` number of elements.

Comment: +1 @downvoters: Why downvote this? This not exactly thrilling, but it is a pitfall well worth mentioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
char16_t x[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 0 };
```

It is similar to doing this (endianness not withstanding):

```
char x[] = { '\0', 'a', '\0', 'b', '\0', 'c', '\0', '\0' };
```

Each character occupies ***two bytes*** in memory.

So when you ask for the length of a `u16string` each **two** bytes is counted as ***one*** character. They are, after all, two-byte (16bit) characters.

**EDIT:**

Your additional question is creating a string ***without*** a null terminator.

Try this:

```
char x[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 0 , 0, 0};
u16string arr = (char16_t*)x;
```

Now the first character is `{'a', 'b'}` the second character is `{'c', 0}` and you also have a null terminator character `{0, 0}`.

Answer (score 4):

No, you have created an array of four elements, the first element is `'a'` converted to `char16_t`, the second is `'b'` converted to `char16_t` etc.

Then you create a `u16string` from that array (converted to a pointer), which reads each element up to the null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

> shouldn't the output be:
>
> arr.length = 2
>   // ab + c(\0)  
>   99

No. 
The elements of `x` are `char16_t`, regardless of that you provide char literals for initialization:

```
#include<iostream>

int main () {
    char16_t x[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 0 };
    std::cout << sizeof(x[0]) << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
2
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71c9b3a2d1202aa7)

**Addendum**, *referring to the EDIT of the question*

*I'd not exactly recommend casting the termination away from strings*. ;)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main () {
    char x[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    std::wstring   ws   = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(x);
    std::u16string u16s = reinterpret_cast<char16_t*>(x);

    std::cout << "sizeof(wchar_t):  "       << sizeof(wchar_t)
              << "\twide string length: "   << ws.length()   
              << std::endl;

    std::cout << "sizeof(char16_t): "       << sizeof(char16_t)
               << "\tu16string length:  "   << u16s.length()   
               << std::endl;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b759a3b6404332ce)

output (compiled with g++)

```
sizeof(wchar_t):  4 wide string length: 1
sizeof(char16_t): 2 u16string length:   2
```

As expected, isn't it.

Comment: I think you have nailed it with an example! Thanks. Can you look at the edited question.

Answer (score -1):

C++ supports the following way to build 16-bit integers from 8-bit integers:

```
char16_t ab = (static_cast<unsigned char>('a') << 8) | 'b';
// (Note: cast to unsigned meant to prevent overflows)
```