# Write a std::u16string to file?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, wstring

I am trying to write a std::u16string to file
It can easily be done with std::string

```
// ... pseudocode
std::wofstream outfile;
outfile.open("words.txt", std::ios_base::app);
outfile << "something"; 
outfile.close();
// ...
```

But how can I write a std::u16string to file?

Thanks

Comment: What do you have try? Have you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952008 ? Full source code with errors?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how the question you linked is related to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `basic_ofstream` whose char type is equivalent to the `u16string` value type, which should be `char16_t`:

```
typedef std::basic_ofstream<char16_t> u16ofstream;

u16ofstream outfile("words.txt", std::ios_base::app);
outfile << someu16string; 
outfile.close();
```

Alternatively, you can convert the `u16string` to a regular `string` and just write it to a plain `ofstream`, but you'll have to handle the conversion and deal with the string's encoding on your own.

`wofstream` may also be compatible with `u16string` on some platforms (specifically Windows), but it's not portable.

Comment: more universal and accuracy method is use std::u16string::value_type instead of char16_t, and analogue for anothe types

Comment: There is a bug with windows, you have to use `typedef std::basic_ofstream<wchar_t> u16ofstream;` but it works fine. Thanks

Comment: so use typedef std::basic_ofstream<std::u16string::value_type> u16ofstream;

Answer (score -1):

Using std::ofstream::write():

```
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(some_u16str), some_u16_str.length() * sizeof(char16_t));
```

I heard that using reinterpret_cast is not recommended, so it may not work in some platforms.